# How to easily make dictionary from list?

Tags: python

I have list:

my_list=[['a',1], ['b', 2]]

I want my_dict['a']=1 and my_dict['b']=2

Is there easy way, without looping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, like this:

```
>>> my_list=[['a',1], ['b', 2]]
>>> my_dict = dict(my_list)
>>> my_dict
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Basically your list is already compatible with the `dict` constructor. (*i.e: A list of 2-item tuples/lists or more precisely an iterable that yields 2-item lists/tuples -- key/value pairs*).

Comment: although Im pretty sure somewhere under the hood this is looping also ... but yeah +1 to both you guys

Comment: It's all hidden away in CPython's implemtnation somewhere :) At least ``dict`` is a builtin type :) AFAIK tehre is no user code except for ``UserDict`` which I'm pretty sure just subclasses ``dict``. There's also ``collections.Mapping``

Answer (score 2):

Use [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
In [138]: my_list=[['a',1], ['b', 2]]

In [139]: my_dict = dict(my_list)

In [140]: my_dict
Out[140]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```